# Permissions error when downloading or quick-looking attachments in mail.app after symlinking Mail Downloads directory

Tags: mail.app, permission, error

Awhile back, I symlinked my `~/Library/Mail Downloads` directory to `~/Downloads` so that my email attachments would be downloaded to the same location that all my other applications download files to.

When I upgraded to Mountain Lion, I noticed that the `Mail Downloads` folder had been restored.  So I deleted it and recreated the symlink the same way I did for previous versions of OS X.

Now, every time I try to download or quick-look an attachment in mail.app, I see the following error (might not be exact; translating from Spanish):

> Mail was unable to save the attachment "..." to disk.  Make sure that the downloads folder has write permissions.

Some of the fixes I have tried:

- Making `~/Downloads` world-writable.
- Removing the symlink and re-creating the directory.

  - Making that directory world-writable.
- Repairing permissions via Disk Utility.
- Changing the location of the Downloads Folder preference for Mail.app to `~/Downloads`.

How do I restore the functionality of my `Mail Downloads` folder (preferably so that it is symlinked to my home `Downloads` folder)?

Comment: Silly question: have you tried changing the "Downloads folder" preference in Mail.app?

Comment: lol That is a good point; I forgot about that.  Unfortunately, changing the preference to my home downloads folder does not solve the issue (although perhaps it helps pinpoint the problem).  I will update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Mountain Lion...

1. Quit Mail
2. Delete the `~/Library/Mail Downloads` folder.
3. Delete the `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail` folder.
4. Restart Mail
5. Rebuild Mailboxes
6. Set your Downloads folder in Mails preferences to ~/Downloads.

   [image: Screenshot of Mail.app preferences dialog with downloads folder highlighted]

Better?

Comment: Maybe just try to set the downloads folder directly in preferences before deleting `com.apple.mail`.

Comment: Sweet.  That did it.  Thanks so much for your help!